# How can I create a table using GORM?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I was trying to create a table of user using GORM, but for some reason it keeps throwing me this error.

```
2022/08/29 01:31:58 /app/infra/database/db.go:26 Error 1075: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

[0.156ms] [rows:0] ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `id` bigint unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT
```

I tried not using `gorm.Model`, and still throws me an error. This is my user model:

```golang
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
}
```

And here is my initialization:

```golang
dsn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@(%s:3306)/%s?charset=utf8&parseTime=True",
        os.Getenv("DB_USERNAME"),
        os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD"),
        os.Getenv("DB_URL"),
        os.Getenv("DB_NAME"),
    )

    db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        panic("error connecting to the database")
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(&user.User{})
    return db, nil
```

Pretty sure I'm doing this correctly, but if you see something strange please let me know, I'm just learning on how to use this ORM

Comment: delete old table, and run the app again

Comment: lol thank you, I can't believe that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the old table will remove the error.